# RDLC Reporting using C#

Tags: c#, reporting, rdlc

I am completely new to reporting in visual studio C#..I tried searching for some tutorials for beginners but i was unsuccessful..I just found code examples that didn't really explain the basics...I wrote some code which complies and runs fine but it DOES NOT SHOW ANYTHING in the report viewer control in Visual Studio 2013..My code is as follows:

```
// This method is in a class named Customers.
// When the user clicks the first column of the datagrid view(I have placed a button 
// in the first column of the datagrid) a new form opens (ReportForm) and i pass
// the DataSet called dsReport to its constructor.


 private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 )
            {

                DataSet dsReport = new DataSet();
                DataTable tbl = dsReport.Tables.Add();

                tbl.Columns.Add("CustomerName", typeof(string));
                tbl.Columns.Add("CustomerAddress", typeof(string));
                tbl.Columns.Add("MaritalStatus", typeof(string));
                tbl.Columns.Add("CustomerType", typeof(string));
                tbl.Columns.Add("ImagePath", typeof(string));

                foreach (Customer cust in customerList)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dsReport.Tables[0].NewRow();
                    dr["CustomerName"] = cust.Name;
                    dr["CustomerAddress"] = cust.Address;
                    dr["MaritalStatus"] = cust.MaritalStatus;
                    dr["CustomerType"] = cust.CustomerType;
                    dr["ImagePath"] = cust.ImagePath;

                    dsReport.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);
                }

                ReportForm report = new ReportForm(dsReport);
                report.Show();

            }
        }


//Following is the code for the ReportForm Class
//I do not get any results in the report viewer
//I just see the message "The source of the report definition has not  been specified"

public ReportForm(DataSet dsReport)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(myReportSource);
            this.reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

        }

        private void ReportForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

        }
```

/* Please note that I have run the code in the debugger and the dataset is being 
populated properly and so is the reportViewer1.LocalReport..Also I HAVE NOT 
Added any datasources to the project AND I HAVE NOT ADDED ANY Report files(.rdl) files 
to the Project */

Lastly can anyone PLEASE answer the following questions:

Q1. Do i absolutely have to include a datasource to work with the report
        viewer tool??

Q2. Do i have to include a .rdl file in the project to display a report??

Q3. Is the report viewer tool and a .rdl file one in the same or are they
        different??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ReportViewer is a control that knows how to render a report.  It just handles the drawing and some other background tasks, it isn't the actual report.  The actual report is the `.rdl` file (Report Definition Language).  It contains all the instructions for generating the report, but it doesn't contain the actual data. The DataSource contains the data that the report operates on.

So to answer your questions specifically:

1. yes (unless your report is completely static and doesn't use any data).
2. no, but you need get the `.rdl` to the ReportViewer somehow.  If you don't want to include it as a file you can embed it as a resource in your application, or even hard code it as a string.  The ReportViewer has a method that accepts a `Stream` also, so anything that can provide a stream can act as the source for the `.rdl`.
3. They are different, as I explained at the very start.

Comment: Thank you Bradley Uffner for the short, clear and concise answer...Please consider the following scenario...I have added the Datasource and the .rdl file to the project and have bound it successfully to the report viewer...The report viewer is now working properly and displaying ALL THE RECORDS...Suppose that I have a form called Form1 which contains a DatagridView with 5 columns..Now when a click the 1st column of any row a new form appears with the report viewer and displays only that row in the report viewer...How do I tackle this???

Comment: On the button click copy the data row to a new DataTable, and use that DataTable as the data source for the report.  The report can only act on the data that you pass it.

Comment: Bradley Uffner I added a dataset to the project and also a .rldc file. Then i added a reportviewer to a form and then bound the dataset and the .rldc file with the report AND IT WORKED. I used parameter to get a single row of data...Now the problem with this approach is that the dataset and .rldc are bound the report viewer. I cant change the dataset through code at runtime due the the binding that is automatically applied...Can you please tell me how i would go about doing all this stuff manually through code...If possible please show working code..Also please see my code at the very start.

Comment: I believe you need to call `.RefreshReport` after changing the data or filter. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportviewer.refreshreport.aspx